# Multipole expansion, same charges

Tags: electromagnetism, gravitational-waves, dipole, dipole-moment, multipole-expansion

I know dipole is defined with 2 opposite charges. That's why in EM dipoles exist, while in gravity they do not.

However, I view multipole expansion as a way to describe how the distribution of charges (or masses) changes around the point where we set the monopole. This only works when we are at a distance $r$ much greater than the distance $r'$ between the charges.

As if we are saying that superposition principle works till we just consider monopole.

So, what's the reason we can't have dipoles with same charges, if it's only a way to describe variations from monopoles?

A reason I found is that if charges are of the same sign, then the dipole depends on the angle you view it from.
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k} q_{k} \vec{r_{k}} = q(\vec{r_{1}}+\vec{r_{2}})
\end{equation}

If they were of opposite sign, they would depend only on the distance.

\begin{equation}
q(\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{r_{2}})
\end{equation}

How does this symmetry affect the existence of a variation term from a monopole? Isn't it fine either way?

It seems not, as there aren't gravitational dipoles (for example, in gravitational waves).

Where is the logic issue?

Comment: I do not understand that given a $\rho(\mathbf x)$ for which $\nabla^2\Phi= -\rho,$ why the expansion $\Phi(\mathbf x) =\frac{1}{4\pi}\int \frac{\rho(\mathbf x')}{|\mathbf {x-x'}|} = \frac{1}{4\pi r}\int \rho(\mathbf x') + \frac{1}{4\pi r^3}\sum_i x_i \int \rho(\mathbf x')x_i' +\frac{1}{4\pi r^5}\sum_{ij}x_i x_j \int \rho(\mathbf x')(3x'_i x'_j-\delta_{ij}r'^2)+...$ would not be a proper multipole expansion whatever $\rho$ may mean? True, all moments will depend on the choice of the coordinate origin but so is the case for moments order $>2$ even for a balanced electric charge distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting caught up in semantics.

Yes gravity can have a dipole term in the multipole expansion because it depends on your choice of coordinates.

But:

1. No mass distribution could have a dipole term and all other terms vanish.
2. No mass distribution could have a dipole term when the origin is chosen as its center of mass.

Comment: Why (2)? That's what I'm asking. What do you mean with (1)? That all multipole terms are 0?